# Ошибка View [welcome] not found

Tags: laravel

Всем привет.Прошу помочь новичку в laravel.Не могу получить доступ к шаблонам.Все работало стабильно но после того как я добавил  новый контроллер `IndexController` то не могу получить доступ к никакому шаблону.Почему так произошло помогите пожалуйста.

> Полное описания папок и изменения файлов

В директории resources  добавил папку **default** и туда же стандартную копию файла `welcome.blade.php`.

В директории `controllers` есть папка `admin` туда же добавил файл **İndexController.php** выглядит следующем образом

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function show(){
        return view('default.welcome');
    }
}
```

И наконец и директории routes файл web.php

```
 Route::get("/", ["as"=>"home","uses"=>"Admin\IndexController@show"]);


 Route::get("/articles/{page}",["uses"=>"Admin\Core@getArticles", "as"=>"articles","middleware"=>"middle"]);
```

Ошибка выводит `InvalidArgumentException`
**View [default.welcome] not found.**
Помогите очень прошу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй папку default переместить в resources/views/

Comment: сработало спасибо вам большое :) и дай бог здоровья